# Por que meu executavel Python é barrado pelo Antivirus? E como resolvo isso?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, antivirus

Estava criando um executável com `pyinstaller` a partir de um arquivo Python simples. O meu antivírus Avast bloqueou o executável alegando ter vírus, apesar de não ter.

Então eu fiz o seguinte código em Python:

```
print("hello world")
```

Chamei o `pyinstaller` para criar o executável desse código com o comando:

```
pyinstaller -wF meuarquivo.py
```

Ele gerou o  executável: `meuarquivo.exe`.

Ao executar o `meuarquivo.exe`, o Avast barrou o programa e moveu para o cofre de vírus. Com isso, as minhas dúvidas são:

- Por que um simples *"hello world"* foi considerado como vírus?
- Como fazer para o meu executável não ser considerado como vírus, já que não é?

Comment: caso ajude encontrei um artigo na internet que mostra o problema, mais nao ajuda a resolver nem explica por que ocorre: https://www.defcon-lab.org/se-python-entao-virus/

Comment: Tem no SOen também: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43777106/1452488

Comment: nossa esse link me ajudou bastante, mas assim em uma das respostas um cara disse pra compilá-los você mesmo em sua máquina, voce sabe oq ele quis dizer com isso?desculpe sou novo nessa area de compilar e fazer executaveis

Comment: Opa! É normal o antivírus reconhecer como vírus, mesmo em um simples "Hello World" pois identificou algum parâmetro do programa que escreveu como código de vírus. Nesse caso, precisa colocar nas exceções do antivírus, dessa forma, ele não vai mais alertar, bloquear e excluir o arquivo. porem... desabilitar uma proteção do sistema não é aconselhável, mesmo que seja um programa conhecido, pois isso abre portar para outras coisas ruins entrarem.

Comment: Pode ser que o pyinstaller tipo "injeta" algumas coisas que o antivírus considera como vírus.
Então, tente mudar para o cx-freeze, e tente compilar o arquivo. Se continuar com vírus pode ser que o seu computador esteja com vírus. Então tente remover o vírus, se não deu certo, formate seu computador.